# Dynamically change Property Name for serialization based on value of another property

Tags: c#, json.net

I know that you can dynamically choose to serialize a property in Json.Net by writing a `ShouldSerialize` method. Is it possible to dynamically change the `PropertyName` for serialization based on the value of another property?

Let's say I have a class:

```
public class Example {
    public int? A {get; set;}
    public int B {get; set;
}
```

If A is null I want the `PropertyName` of B to be a certain value, and if A is not null, then I want the `PropertyName` to be another value.

Comment: May be if use a constructor where you do this conditional initializing..

Comment: What's wrong with `B.PropertyName = (A == null) ? "somevalue" : "someothervalue";` ?

Comment: @emsimpson92 is there something special I need to do to be able access the `PropertyName` of a property?

Comment: If you want to be that flexible on serialization i would not go with using a class and manipulate the class. Simlpy use jsonnewton.

Comment: I would like to use Json.Net to achieve this @Aldert. Can you point me in the right direction to achieving this?